# Recommended Format for Refresh Token

Tags: authentication, security, oauth-2.0

I am making an application that generates refresh token that implements JWT token authentication, and I am not sure what format should I use to identify the refresh token. Initially, I thought that it should be in JWT token format, but based on my googling, it seems like it is represented in a UUID or hashed format? Just wondering whether I should make it JWT token format, or it does not matter in the case of refresh token?

Thanks in advance for helping to clarify this issue.

From here https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/refresh-tokens/main/ [refresh token response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0NjI.png) it shows the refresh token format is not in JWT format.

Answer (score 0):

First decide how you want to model this, which might work like this:

- User authenticates (and optionally consents)
- Create a delegation to represent the user action
- Delegation is stored as a database row
- Fields include sub, client_id, refresh_token_hash, scopes_issued, claims_issued, issuance time, expiry time
- Subsequent token requests are validated against the persisted state

The hash might be the returned to clients, or they may be given a different identifier. It is a pointer to backend state.

You might also need to implement support for refresh token rotation, revocation, auditing of tokens issued and so on. Consider using an authorization server, as described in RFC6749, to handle this stuff for you.